# How to query rows by intraday time range in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I have a column that consists of the datetime for each entry in the table. The entries are across many days and across all times. I want to filter only for entries that happened between a certain time period in the day, like between 10am and 1pm. How does one do that?

The datetimes are stored as a string in ISO-8601 format. Ex: 2021-01-22T12:50:00-05:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep the [sqlite Date and Time Functions doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) handy.

Something like:

```
WHERE strftime("%H:%M",yourdate) between "10:00" and "13:00"
```

should accomplish the task.

Comment: Side note: Such a WHERE clause is not [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), so it's going to be rather slow in larger data sets. If that turns out to be an issue, I'd recommend setting up an additional column e.g. `hourOfDay` (or `timeOfDay`) and filling that e.g. using an insert/update trigger. This way the WHERE clause could take advantage of indexes again.

Comment: Yea, it would greatly benefit my program if the dates were indexable, so I'm probably going with additional columns for the date. Although, the strftime() approach did answer my question and helped me do some prototyping.